# Fixing ArcMap colour palette?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.2, symbology

My ArcMap 10.2 colour palette seems to be glitching out. What I think are the 'base' colours (those which are always available even when you don't have any style references) keep getting added. I think they might get added again each time I open arc, until the palette reaches capacity. I can add in style references such as the ESRI-optimized if there's room in the palette, but they eventually get overridden by the base colours. I've found I can wipe the palette by deleting my personal styles file but then the same thing happens again.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Edit: I think the colours that keep getting added might be the ESRI-CAD style? Always seems to be checked in the Style References window.

[image]